# API with swagger in magento 1 or other tool

Tags: magento-1.9, api, tools, swagger

I am trying to find out way to create api for magento 1.

can we use **swagger for magento 1** or any other tools available for magento 1.9.

Please give suggestion or need to create from scratch ?

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/

Comment: @nortonuser he is asking for magento 1.x and Swagger is only available in Magento 2.x

Answer (score 0):

> can we use swagger for magento 1 or any other tools available for
>   magento 1.9 ?

No, Swagger is only available in **Magento 2.x** You can check on **[devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/)** site also there is title mentioned that "Magento Commerce for B2B
"

You can refer the below links:

> For Magento Open Source 1.5 to 1.9

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html

**Magento devdocs** provides all basic **REST API** for the **Magento 1.x** and it is **Authentic** source

you can develop it from here **from scratch**

> For Magento 1.x API documentation,

1. [Magento 1.x SOAP API](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html)
2. [Magento 1.x REST API](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest-api-index.html)